# Error al crear un DataFrame con groupby().sum() usando Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Buen día. 
Desconozco si ya hay una pregunta similar, si ya existe, les agradecería que me dirigieran a dicha respuesta, de lo contrario, les agradecería su apoyo aquí.
Tengo que realizar un análisis de unos datos de ventas de productos. La tabla consiste de tres columnas, Fecha, Producto, Venta, como se muestra abajo:\

```
datos = pd.read_excel(r"/content/datos.xlsx")
datos.head()
```

| FECHA | Producto | VENTA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-01 | Producto 19 | 17632.1195 |
| 2021-08-01 | Producto 15 | 3213.0000 |
| 2021-08-01 | Producto 6 | 818286.8315 |
| 2021-08-01 | Producto 10 | 607534.1000 |
| 2021-08-01 | Producto 9 | 599290.2390 |

intento crear un dataframe a partir de este usando:

```
productos = datos.groupby("Producto").sum("VENTA")
productos.head()
```

Sin embargo, al imprimir este DF, los productos los asigna como Index.

| Index | VENTA |
| --- | --- |
| Producto |  |
| Producto 1 | 3.591122e07 |
| Producto 10 | 1.221809e07 |
| Producto 11 | 4.163053e05 |
| Producto 12 | 4.136830e05 |
| Producto 13 | 4.134738e05 |

Como puedo resolver este problema? Intenté hacer la columna y el index "manualmente" de esta forma:

```
productos["Producto"] = productos.index
productos.index = [*range(0,20)]
```

Pero para DFs grandes sería difícil controlar esto.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar la instrucción 'reset_index', y el modificador 'inplace'
En tu caso, tienes que añadir esta línea después de agrupar:

```
productos.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

La descripción de la documentación en este enlace:
[pandas.DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).